# Got stuck with Imebra integration

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, imebra

It would be helpful if you could help with the steps to integrate Imebra with swift project. I went through [official website](https://imebra.com/wp-content/uploads/documentation/html/compiling_imebra.html#os-x-ios-specific-instructions) but xcode project is not getting generated. Following is the error I faced:

> -- The C compiler identification is unknown
>   -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (project):   No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (project):   No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
>   could be found.
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/Users/xxxxx/documents/iOS/artifacts/build/imebra_for_ios/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>   See also
>   "/Users/xxxxx/documents/iOS/artifacts/build/imebra_for_ios/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

I want to read, view and extract data from dicom files in iOS. There are other protocols too which I would have to use but for now viewing, reading and extracting metadata of dicom file are priorities.

Following are my tech specifications:

> Swift = 3.0
>
> Xcode = 8.3.3
>
> Mac OS = Sierra, 10.12

Comment: It looks like cmake is not configured correctly. If you have homebrew (https://brew.sh/) then a simple "brew install cmake" should suffice to install and configure cmake correctly

Comment: I have installed cmake with brew, with "brew install cmake" command.

Comment: https://github.com/symless/synergy/issues/5666 the comment from koopatroopa120 solves the issue